# How to put xcode in my /applications folder, preferably in a /developer sub-folder

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Not sure why, but currently the only way I can access xcode is by going into finder and typing 'xcode'.

How can I link xcode from my applications folder, and pref. put it into a 'developer' sub-folder.

(new'ish to mac)

Answer (score 2):

Xcode is installed in `/Developer/Applications/`, just open it using spotlight and when the icon is in the dock, right click and select `Keep in dock`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find xcode in spotlight.
2. press command+enter to open it in a Finder window
3. drag the icon to the dock
4. or drag it to another folder while
   pressing command+alt (to create a
   link/alias)